# Multiple duplicates links are not added to the "Linked" section immediately

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, linked-questions

Whenever a questions is closed with multiple duplicates, the "Linked" section only shows the original duplicate the question was closed with. The subsequent edits are not updated.

[image]

Half an hour later, I checked the question again and it is update now.

[image]

When a link to a question is added in a comment, it is immediately added to the "Linked" section. Is there a reason for the delay in the case of duplicate list?

Comment: Should I blame caching?

Comment: @Luuklag there is no delay when a link to another question is added in the comments. The first screenshot is 15 minutes after the question was closed.

Comment: Is the [live-refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/live-refresh/info) / heartbeat tag a useful addition to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed now. The *Linked* section is immediately updated.